# Problem with extended DecimalPipe after upgrading to Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular11

Upgrading from Angular 10 to 11 and running into a problem with an extension we have on the DecimalPipe.

The pipe code:

```
 export class CustomNumberFormatPipe extends DecimalPipe implements PipeTransform {

 transform(value: string): string | null {
    if (!value) {
        return null;
    }
    value = value.toString().replace(/,/g, '');
    return super.transform(value);
}
```

and the error:

```
 Property 'transform' in type 'CustomNumberFormatPipe' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'DecimalPipe'.
 Type '(value: string) => string' is not assignable to type '{ (value: string | number, 
 digitsInfo?: string, locale?: string): string; (value: null, digitsInfo?: string, locale?: 
 string): null; (value: string | number, digitsInfo?: string, locale?: string): 
 string; }'.
 Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'null'.
```

and the DecimalType definition:

```
 export declare class DecimalPipe implements PipeTransform {
   private _locale;
   constructor(_locale: string);
   transform(value: number | string, digitsInfo?: string, locale?: string): string | null;
   transform(value: null | undefined, digitsInfo?: string, locale?: string): null;
   transform(value: number | string | null | undefined, digitsInfo?: string, locale?: string): string | null;
   static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<DecimalPipe, never>;
   static ɵpipe: ɵngcc0.ɵɵPipeDefWithMeta<DecimalPipe, "number">;
```

}

The only solution I've found so far is to modify the actual DecimalPipe in common but I don't really feel confident doing that.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try changing this `transform(value: string): string` to this `transform(value: string): string | null`.

Comment: Given that `DecimalPipe` now accepts a `value` that's `null`, your subclass must too. You already have the logic for that in the actual implementation, just add it to the type definition.

Comment: @R.Richards, tried that but get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just go to the `DecimalPipe` declaration and copy its `transform` signature to your pipe:

```
transform(value: number | string, digitsInfo?: string, locale?: string): string | null;
transform(value: null | undefined, digitsInfo?: string, locale?: string): null;
transform(value: number | string | null | undefined, digitsInfo?: string, locale?: string): string | null {
    if (!value) {
        return null;
    }
    value = value.toString().replace(/,/g, '');
    return super.transform(value);
}
```

Comment: @D Pro, I added the definition to the question, I'm not sure which one to add

Comment: all of them. I have updated my answer, please check

Comment: Thanks man, that did it!